# Combine two validation rules - Only System admin should be able to click a checkbox when Opportunity already assigned to an owner

Tags: validation-rule

I have two validation rules. I've not been able to combine the two rules into one.

One rule: Only system admin should be able to click a check box called 'new order' when an opportunity is already assigned an owner.

Second rule: Prevent users from unchecking the 'new order' checkbox if already checked true.

Here are the two separate rules that works separately that I have done:

First rule:

```
AND(IsNewOrder__c = TRUE,
NOT ISBLANK( AssignedTo__c ),
$Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator')
```

Second rule:

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(IsNewOrder__c),
PRIORVALUE(IsNewOrder__c) = true,
$Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator')
```

Any help to combine these two into one would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** - Updated Bottom Version - I think it's what you want.

It depends on which way you want to combine them - both or either of them.

Either can cause the rule to fire:

```
OR (
  AND(IsNewOrder__c = TRUE, NOT ISBLANK( AssignedTo__c ), $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator'),
  AND( ISCHANGED(IsNewOrder__c), PRIORVALUE(IsNewOrder__c) = true, $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator')
)
```

Both needed to cause the rule to fire:

```
AND (
  AND(IsNewOrder__c = TRUE, NOT ISBLANK( AssignedTo__c ), $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator'),
  AND( ISCHANGED(IsNewOrder__c), PRIORVALUE(IsNewOrder__c) = true, $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator')
)
```

Finally a fancier way - this way avoids writing the administrator rule twice:

```
AND (
  $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',
  ISCHANGED(IsNewOrder__c), 
  OR (
    AND (
      NOT (ISBLANK( AssignedTo__c )),
      IsNewOrder__c = TRUE
    ),
    PRIORVALUE(IsNewOrder__c) = true
  )
)
```

Comment: Fantastic. It worked! Thank you @ Caspar and Sahil! :-) And yes, the fancier way is preferable. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If it worked for you, you can mark as accepted ;)